# Pandas Add one day after midnight

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add one day after midnight.
For example, I have a column typed datetime64 in Dataframe, Pandas.

Originally, my csv file only has time like 12:13:00, 07:12:53, 02:33:27.

I wanted to add a date into the time cuz the file name has a date. The thing is that I have to add one day on time after midnight.

Here's an example.

This is original data with the file name mycsv_20180101.csv

```
time
22:00:00
23:00:00
03:00:00
```

This is what I want.

```
time
2018-01-01 22:00:00
2018-01-01 23:00:00
2018-01-02 03:00:00 # this is the point.
```

Is there any idea for it?

I've thought about it for a while and my idea is

firstly, add a date.
Secondly, `df['time'].apply(lambda x: x + pd.to_timedelta('1d') if x.dt.hour < 6 else False)` # before 6am, I assume that that's a next day

but it says `'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I don't know why...

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Are they in a chronological order? What happens to today's 3 am?

Comment: That's data of the order time of a restaurant running from 6pm to 4am. Thus, there is no today's 3am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your dataframe and date from file are like these:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["18:10:0","19:10:00","20:10:00","21:10:00","22:10:00","23:10:00","00:10:00","01:10:00","02:10:00","03:10:00"]})
file_date = '20180101'
```

You first need to add `file_date` to your data

```
df.time = df.time.apply(lambda x: ' '.join((file_date, x)))
```

which yields:

```
    time
0   20180101 18:10:00
1   20180101 19:10:00
2   20180101 20:10:00
3   20180101 21:10:00
4   20180101 22:10:00
5   20180101 23:10:00
6   20180101 00:10:00
7   20180101 01:10:00
8   20180101 02:10:00
9   20180101 03:10:00
```

What you need to do is convert them into `datetime` type and add a day if hour is smaller than 4.

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time).apply(lambda x: x + pd.DateOffset(days=1) if x.hour <=3 else x)
```

which gives your desired output of:

```
    time
0   2018-01-01 18:10:00
1   2018-01-01 19:10:00
2   2018-01-01 20:10:00
3   2018-01-01 21:10:00
4   2018-01-01 22:10:00
5   2018-01-01 23:10:00
6   2018-01-02 00:10:00
7   2018-01-02 01:10:00
8   2018-01-02 02:10:00
9   2018-01-02 03:10:00
```

Comment: It really works. That's all I need and I can move on to the next step! You save my day.

Comment: @sunsets Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.